# Too many lights in one place! Unity URP 8 Max lights? Workaround?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, lighting, urp

I have a control panel with several lights and buttons with lights on it. I can't have more than 8 render due to **URP's** "per object limit".

What would be the best way to go about this?

- Would using emissive materials be a workaround ***OR...***
- is there some way to get these lights to all load when looking directly at the panel (VR)?

If I turn and look at one side of the panel then they will blink and load correctly but if direct on with all the lights firing at the same time then they will not render correctly.

[image]

I've attempted to revert to Unity's [*Built-in Render Pipeline*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/built-in-render-pipeline.html) because I saw somewhere that you can up the limit. But it's just not worth it due to all of the URP textures that would break if I went that route so I'm looking for a solid work around that will allow me to get all of these lights to render and blink accordingly.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar?

Comment: How about a mixture of real-time and _baked emissive?_ https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html

Comment: seems to me that this is gonna be the only way to do things is to use emissive materials thanks for the documentation

Comment: Great! Let us know how you go. :)